# Django - CreateView get_context_data TypeError

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a mixin on top of my app/views.py:

```
class RefereeViewMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser and \
           not self.request.user.has_group("referee"):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(RefereeViewMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

And also a view which is derived from my custom mixin and CreateView:

```
class RefereeResultCreateView(RefereeViewMixin, CreateView):
    category = None
    template_name = "referee/result_create.html"
    fields = ["minutes", "seconds", "miliseconds", "disqualification"]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("order_list", args=[self.category])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RefereeResultCreateView, self).get_context_data(
            **kwargs)
        context["project"] = Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        result = form.save(commit=False)
        result.project = Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        result.save()

        messages.success(self.request, _(
            "Result entry for {} project created.".format(result.name)))
        return super(RefereeResultCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Finally, my final view which is derived from RefereeResultCreateView:

```
class RefereeFireFighterResultCreateView(RefereeResultCreateView):
    model = FireFighterResult
    category = "fire_fighter"
    fields = RefereeResultCreateView.fields + [
        "extinguish_success", "extinguish_failure", "wall_hit"]
```

And the pattern is like that:

```
    url(r'^fire_fighter/(?P<pk>\d+)/create/$',
        RefereeFireFighterResultCreateView.as_view(),
        name="referee_fire_fighter_result_create")
```

However, when I go to /app/fire_fighter/some_id/create/ I got TypeError. It tells me **super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**. When I debug it, I see that **RefereeResultCreateView**'s **get_context_data** method causes that error. If I don't override that method, I don't see any errors. When I override it at RefereeFireFighterResultCreateView class, I don't see any errors.

I can overcome the problem. However, I think it is not the elegant way. Actually, it is very dirty. Also, I am curious about the reason. Why it doesn't work in the way I expect? What is the elegant solution?

**UPDATED**

Here's the traceback:

https://gist.github.com/ilkerkesen/e65fefa66890758bcdcd

Comment: Can you copy/paste full stacktrace here? Unlike you, I suspect `RefereeViewMixin` calling `super.dispatch()` that is causing the error, as `object` has no `dispatch` method.

Comment: Your approach seems correct and I have used it many times. Is it the actual code you pasted here because a typo can often be the cause of such errors.

Comment: @ozgur, I've just added the traceback.

Comment: @Emma, I don't think a typo's existence.

Comment: @IlkerKesen Have you checked the type of `self` in `get_context_data` method? Clearly it is not `RefereeResultCreateView` type. Maybe `super(self.__class_, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` would help.

Comment: Are you sure the login required decorator is allowed? The docs tell you to do it with a mixin on class based views.